# Vim: Show no of matches at bottom of buffer

Tags: search, vim, find

In Vim, when searching a page for a word, we can use 'n' to move to the next word. If the next word is off screen, the buffer window will adjust to show the contents of the file with the 'next' word on the last line of the buffer.

What I'd like is to have that 'found' word 4 lines from the bottom. This would provide a little more context around the found word. Is this possible with some edits to my .vim file?

Comment: [`set scrolloff=4`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'scrolloff')

Comment: @phd that works perfectly, thank you. I'm unable to tag your comment as preferred answer, are you able to add your commend as an answer?